# Gstreamer Java "No such Gstreamer factory" - why?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, gstreamer

I'm trying to run the Gstreamer Java tutorials (https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/Tutorials). But I run into a "No such Gstreamer factory" error now.

From a hunt around the internet it seems to be something to do with the computer architecture (32 or 64 bit) but I can't see how to resolve the problem.

I'm running OSX 10.8.5 (64 bit), Java 1.7.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Ed

EDIT:
`java -version`

`java version "1.7.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`

And the code to run is:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.gstreamer.*;
import org.gstreamer.swing.VideoComponent;

public class VideoTest {

    public VideoTest() {
    }
    private static Pipeline pipe;
    private static String libDir;
    private static final Object[][] DEPENDENCIES = {
        // glib libraries
        {"gio-2.0", new String[]{}, true},
        {"glib-2.0", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gmodule-2.0", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gobject-2.0", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gthread-2.0", new String[]{}, true},
        // Core gstreamer libraries  
        {"gstapp-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstaudio-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstbase-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstbasevideo-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        //{"gstcdda-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstcontroller-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstdataprotocol-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstfft-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstinterfaces-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        //{"gstnet-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstnetbuffer-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstpbutils-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstphotography-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstreamer-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstriff-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstrtp-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstrtsp-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstsdp-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        //{"gstsignalprocessor-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gsttag-0.10", new String[]{}, true},
        {"gstvideo-0.10", new String[]{}, true},};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        libDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        //MAC64
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("OS")) {
            if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("64")) {
                libDir = libDir + "/MAC64";
            }
        }
        //PC64
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win")) {
            if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("64")) {
                libDir = libDir + "\\PC64";
            }
        }
        //PC32
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win")) {
            if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("32")) {
                libDir = libDir + "\\PC32";
            }
        }

        for (Object[] a : DEPENDENCIES) {
            try {
                NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(a[0].toString(), libDir);
                Native.loadLibrary(a[0].toString(), DummyLibrary.class);
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex) {
                System.out.println("Error loading: " + a[0].toString());
            }
        }


        Gst.setUseDefaultContext(false);

        args = Gst.init("VideoTest", args);

        pipe = new Pipeline("VideoTest");
        final Element videosrc = ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", "source");
        final Element videofilter = ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter");
        videofilter.setCaps(Caps.fromString("video/x-raw-yuv, width=720, height=576"
                + ", bpp=32, depth=32, framerate=25/1"));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                VideoComponent videoComponent = new VideoComponent();
                Element videosink = videoComponent.getElement();
                pipe.addMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);
                Element.linkMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);

                // Now create a JFrame to display the video output
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Video Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(videoComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                videoComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 576));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                // Start the pipeline processing
                pipe.setState(State.PLAYING);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface DummyLibrary extends Library {
    }
}
```

Where the directories hold the lib/dylib files. This is based on code from Praxis LIVE (https://code.google.com/p/praxis/).

Comment: Can you please post the code, the command you run to start the code and the result of running `java -version` from the command line? Thanks.

Comment: Edit to the question. Thanks @Nicholas!

Answer (score 1):

From their [website](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/news/) :

*The GStreamer team is pleased to announce binary builds for GStreamer 1.0.7, the plugin modules and all their dependencies ... Builds are currently provided for Windows (32/64 bit), Mac OS X (32/64 bit x86) and Android (ARM). Future releases will include support for iOS.* 2013-06-10

You aren't facing a compatibility problem, but this error `No such Gstreamer factory` should be a missing package of GStreamer containing the factory you try to use.

Check your [installation](https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/GettingHelp) by running `gst-launch videotestsrc ! autovideosink` and look for any issue

Comment: Thanks. I want to make this a self-contained application so have moved away from the installed gstreamer - see the code above. What have I missed in that?